# How to move the focus from a QLineEdit to a QTableView editable cell

Tags: qt, qwidget, qtableview, qlineedit, qt5.4

I am using a `QMainWindow` with few `QLineEdits` and with some `QPushButtons` in it. When the focus is in a `QLineEdit` (if I type something in the `QLineEdit`) and if I press the F5 key, I want to show a `QDialog`.

That `QDialog` contains a `QTableView`. My question is, when I press the F5 key, I want to move the focus from the `QLineEdit` to the `QTableView`'s cell. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you please include the code of your previous attempts to set the focus to the specific cell and tell us what exactly goes wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass `QLineEdit` and override `keyPressEvent()` to detect when the F5 key is pressed, or install an event filter on the `QLineEdit`.

If you create and show the dialog during the key event processing the dialog will automatically receive a focus in event and the first widget in the dialog that accepts focus will be the widget in focus. So either let the `QTableView` be the first widget, or explicitly give the focus to it using `setFocus()`.

If the dialog is already constructed or is a non-modal dialog which is already open, you need a pointer to the dialog so that you can show it/give it the focus when the F5 key is pressed.

If you want to move to a certain cell in the `QTableView` you of course also need to know the cell associated with your `QLineEdit`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Daniel Hedberg. That helped me alot. I have another question. How the focus will change if i use a QWidget instead of a QDialog. I know QDialog automatically recieves the focus. But how about for a QWidget?

Comment: You need to have a pointer to the widget so that you can give it focus by calling widget->setFocus(). If you found my answer helpful, feel free to accept it and/or upvote it. Thanks.

Comment: Your answer was really helpful and i tried and it works, When i close the child widget i want to revert back my focus to the QLineEdit (but this doesn't works anymore).